# Filling up the Cayley table and finding Self-inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The set $G$ is given by $G = \{a, b, c, d, f, g, h, k\}$.

$(G, *)$ is a group, with identity $k$, under a certain binary operation $*$.

$a * b = c$,

$b * a = d$,

$f * f = a$,

$g * g = b$,

$h * h = c$.

How many self-inverses does $(G, *)$ have?

**Edit** (converted from answer)

Order Is 8
Not an Albelian

According to isomorphic rule
if an order is 8 and not an albelian there can be only 2 or 6 self inverse
and if u draw the uncomplete cayley table..
 u will find having 6 self inverse is impossible 
therefore the answer is 2 self inverse...(tricky question)

Answer (score 2):

> $(G, *)$ is a group, with identity $k$, under a certain binary operation $*$.

Note: that for $G = \{a, b, c, d, f, g, h, k\},\;$ the *order* of $\,G\,$ is:$\;|G| = 8.\,$  By the [Theorem of Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), the order of the elements of $G$ apart from the identity, which has order $1$, can only be $2, \, 4,\,\text{ or} \; 8$.

Recall that the order of a an element $g$ in a finite group is the order of the group it generates: $\operatorname{ord}(g) = |\langle g\rangle| = n$, where $n$ is the least positive integer such that $g^n = 1$ (where $1$ here represents the identity). In this case, the identity element of $G$ is $k$, so an element $g \in G$ is a self-inverse if and only if $g * g = k \iff g^2 = k\iff \operatorname{ord}(g) = 2.$

- $a * b = c,\quad$
- $b * a = d$,

  Since $a * b \neq b * a$,  $G$ is not abelian (and hence, certainly not cyclic), hence no element in $G$ is of order $8$.
- $f * f = a$, $\quad f^2 = a \neq k \implies f$ not self-inverse,
  so it cannot have order $2$: it must have order $4$, and so $f^4 = a^2 = a*a = k$. $a$ has order $2$, thus is a self-inverse.
- $g * g = b$,  $\quad g^2 = b \neq k \implies g$ is not a self-inverse:
  so it cannot have order $2$: must have order $4$, and so $g^4 = b^2 = b * b = k$. So $b$ has order $2$, thus is a self-inverse.
- $h * h = c$. $\quad h^2 = c \neq k \implies h$ not self-inverse:
  $h$ must
  have order $4$, and so $h^4 = c^2 = c*c = k$. $c$ has order $2$,
  thus, is a self-inverse.

Putting two and two together...we are left with only $d$, which can only have order equal to.......? Why?

Challenge: Can you tell which group this is?

Comment: Very nice including the challenge! +1

Comment: I cannot tell which group this is, in fact I do not believe such a group can exist. In $D_4$ and $Q_8$, the square of every element is central, whereas in this group $f^2 = a$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

From the first two equalities, we know what neither $a$ nor $b$ are the identity element (can you see why?), which then says that $f$ and $g$ are not self-inverses.

We also have that $c$ is not the identity. If it was we would have $a*b = 1$ (here, I'm using $1$ for the identity - typically we would use $e$, but that would cause confusion here). This would also imply that $b*a = 1$ but we know that is not the case. Thus $h$ is not a self-inverse. We also know that $d$ is not the identity.

Following similar logic, can anything be said about $a*a$, $b*b$ and $c*c$?

Comment: the identity is *given* in the problem: $G = (G, *)$ with identity $k$...

Comment: Apparently I can't read. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Cameron: Believe me, we've all done that...we've all missed a part of a question; I've even mis-interpreted entire questions!